# Docker build failed with Gitlab CI, service didn't start properly

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci

So I wanted to move my build step of my docker image to Gitlab CI. Since this is my first time using Gitlab CI to build a Docker Image, I'm guessing that I have an error in my configuration somewhere.

The Error I get is: `ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/_ping": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.16.1.1:53: no such host`

The runner itself works, I am successfully testing my project with pytest in the first stage.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /vpapp

COPY . .

RUN pip install .

EXPOSE 8501

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "src/vierpunktmessung/app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0", "--browser.serverPort=8501", "--browser.serverAddress=***** (redacted)"]
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
    - test
    - publish
    - deploy

variables:
    TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
    TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - .venv/


test:
    tags:
        - runner01
    image: python:3.12.1-bookworm
    stage: test
    script:
        - python -m venv .venv
        - source .venv/bin/activate
        - pip install -e .
        - pip install pytest
        - python -m pytest --junitxml=report.xml
    artifacts:
        when: always
        reports:
            junit: report.xml

publish:
    tags:
        - runner01
    image: docker:latest
    stage: publish
    services:
        - docker:dind
    script:
        - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
        - docker push $TAG_LATEST
```

Log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.4.1 (d89a789a)
  on gitlab-runner-01 ********, system ID: ****************
Preparing the "docker" executor 00:37
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:6091c7bd89fd2789606b49815b2b9ea1a9142ee6e8762089ab3975afd6784a6c for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:1b9844d846ce3a6a6af7013e999a373112c3c0450aca49e155ae444526a2c45e ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
*** WARNING: Service runner-******-project-54012-concurrent-0-800ab30c6863487b-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-******-project-54012-concurrent-0-800ab30c6863487b-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
2023-12-18T13:43:57.661670033Z waiting for TCP connection to 172.17.0.2 on [2375 2376]...
2023-12-18T13:43:57.661719769Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
2023-12-18T13:43:57.662046503Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
2023-12-18T13:43:58.662376048Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
2023-12-18T13:43:58.662407600Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
2023-12-18T13:43:59.663019590Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
2023-12-18T13:43:59.663108281Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
2023-12-18T13:44:00.663636106Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2376...
2023-12-18T13:44:00.663681929Z dialing 172.17.0.2:2375...
Service container logs:
2023-12-18T13:43:59.664635248Z Certificate request self-signature ok
2023-12-18T13:43:59.664657831Z subject=CN = docker:dind server
2023-12-18T13:43:59.683578956Z /certs/server/cert.pem: OK
2023-12-18T13:44:00.283957810Z Certificate request self-signature ok
2023-12-18T13:44:00.283994910Z subject=CN = docker:dind client
2023-12-18T13:44:00.303875863Z /certs/client/cert.pem: OK
2023-12-18T13:44:00.307856391Z ip: can't find device 'nf_tables'
2023-12-18T13:44:00.309849165Z modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
2023-12-18T13:44:00.311224190Z ip: can't find device 'ip_tables'
2023-12-18T13:44:00.312297008Z ip_tables              32768  2 iptable_nat,iptable_filter
2023-12-18T13:44:00.312312542Z x_tables               40960  5 xt_conntrack,xt_MASQUERADE,xt_addrtype,iptable_filter,ip_tables
2023-12-18T13:44:00.312747425Z modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
2023-12-18T13:44:00.315481382Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2023-12-18T13:44:00.315540711Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2023-12-18T13:44:00.315546317Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2023-12-18T13:44:00.316745444Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
*********
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:6091c7bd89fd2789606b49815b2b9ea1a9142ee6e8762089ab3975afd6784a6c for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:1b9844d846ce3a6a6af7013e999a373112c3c0450aca49e155ae444526a2c45e ...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on runner-******-project-54012-concurrent-0 via gitlab-srmuc-01...
Getting source from Git repository 00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/oe112/vierpunktmessung/.git/
Checking out def5ed33 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Removing .pytest_cache/
Removing .venv/
Removing report.xml
Removing src/vierpunktmessung/__pycache__/
Removing tests/__pycache__/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache 00:08
Checking cache for default-protected...
cache.zip is up to date                            
WARNING: .venv/bin/python: chmod .venv/bin/python: no such file or directory (suppressing repeats) 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00
Using docker image sha256:6091c7bd89fd2789606b49815b2b9ea1a9142ee6e8762089ab3975afd6784a6c for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:1b9844d846ce3a6a6af7013e999a373112c3c0450aca49e155ae444526a2c45e ...
$ docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/_ping": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.16.1.1:53: no such host
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that the company runner I used didn't have Docker in docker set up. It turns out, that Docker in docker can lead to an unsafe configuration.

The alternative and recommended solution is to use [Kaniko](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html), which worked great.